# Eclipse vs. OSGi Framework ?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-plugin

Should I create an eclipse plugin with target platform OSGi or without it ?

from Eclipse help

"If you do not intend to use the Eclipse extension registry, then you should use the OSGi framework option. If you select the OSGi framework option, you will not end up with dependencies on the runtime layer. Moreover, PDE will restrict the available templates and the code generated for you to the OSGi layer."

What I can't do when I choose OSGi? Why would I choose OSGi when its less powerful for plugins ?

Answer (score 4):

This setting just adjusts the dependencies of the soon-to-be-created plugin. You can create a simple bundle and add dependencies to the eclipse infrastructure bundles - will you manage the versioned dependencies by hand?

Also, depending on this setting the wizard will offer to create project scaffolding based on a template for the selected eclipse version; f.e. help, preferences, UI contributions, and whatever else you have installed that has a registered template that applies.

In essence, if your plugin will only be used within eclipse, you don't need to think about it, just set the desired Eclipse version. If your plugin should be also usable in other OSGi frameworks, only then is any decision necessary.

Comment: why would my plugin be usable in other OSGi frameworks? Eclipse plugin must depend on Eclipse API, so it should be useless without it.

Comment: Eclipse Plugin Development Environment (PDE) also happens to be one of the best tools for developing OSGi bundles for other environments besides Eclipse. There is a lot of "plugin" terminology throughout, but that's just for historic reasons. An OSGi bundle developed for other environments, would obviously not reference Eclipse API. It would reference bundles from that environment.

Comment: ehhh ... looked at bndtools lately?

Comment: @IAdapter - because it is possible to write Eclipse plugings that reuse other bundles that are not Eclipse-specific. Think of a JAR with extra OSGi manifest, that provides non-UI functionality; and an Eclipse plugin that adds that functionality to Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Our simple rule of thumb that handles almost all cases is, if it does not provide any UI functionality, then it is an OSGI bundle.  In this case, none of the SWT specific libraries and frameworks are being used.

You asked "What I can't do when I choose OSGi? Why would I choose OSGi when its less powerful for plugins ?", so I will ask "are you writing a plugin, or an OSGi bundle"?

They are not the same thing.  A plugin is a bundle, with the UI extensions added on.  This is not a matter of it (OSGi project) being less powerful, it simply doesn't provide the extra functionality required to code a UI, as this is NOT part of OSGi.  So if you are writing a pure OSGi bundle, then create an OSGi project, without the extra dependencies and artifacts that are simply not required.  If you are writing a UI, then it should be a plugin project.